# How can I highlight all captions in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I am trying to set all captions in a document with a large number of tables and figures to the same font. Is there a way to select only the captions to amend the font at once?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to select only the captions to amend the font at once?

> When you use the captioning feature, Word automatically formats the
>   caption using the Caption style. **By default, the Caption style uses
>   the same typeface as your Normal style, except it is bold. If you want
>   to use a different set of attributes for your captions, all you need
>   to do is change the Caption style.** Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Display the Home tab of the ribbon.
> 2. Click the small icon at the bottom-right of the Styles group. Word displays the Styles pane at the right side of the desktop.
> 3. Click Options at the bottom of the Styles pane. Word displays the Style Pane Options dialog box.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Using the Select Styles to Show drop-down list, choose All Styles.
> 5. Click OK to close the Style Pane Options dialog box.
> 6. In the Styles pane, scroll through the list of styles until you see the Caption style.
> 7. Hover the mouse pointer over the Caption style name. Notice that a downward-pointing arrow appears at the right side of the style name.
> 8. Click on the downward-pointing arrow and choose the Modify option from the resulting menu. Word displays the Modify Style dialog
>      box.
> 9. Click on Format and choose the portion of the style you want to change. The options available through the Format button utilize dialog
>      boxes with which you are already familiar.
> 10. Click on OK to save your modifications.
> 11. Close the Styles pane, if desired.

Source [Formatting Captions](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T013267_Formatting_Captions.html)